# Safely publish array elements

Tags: java, arrays, multithreading

This question is concerned with safe publishing of array contents within multi threaded java programms.

Let's assume I have some arbitrary array of Objects:

```
Object[] myArray = ...
```

Now this array is handed over to another thread, maybe like this:

```
new Thread() {
    public void run() {
        // ...
        Object o = myArray[0];
        // ...
    }
};
```

My question is, will the new Thread observe the values within the array as 'expected' if no further synchronization is in place? Does this depend on whether the array itself is a (final/volatile) field or a local variable? Are subsequent modifications of the array from the first thread immediately visible to the new thread?
What would be the most efficient way of safely publishing the array's elements?

Comment: Yes, because you haven't `start`ed the `Thread` yes. `start` establishes happens-before.

Comment: It is a very bad idea to share arrays like this. Just because you only want it to be read from doesn't mean that some other observer might become a modifier all of a sudden. There are much better patterns for sharing data between threads

Comment: In my case, I'm handing an AOP `MethodInvocation` (obtained from intercepting a method call) over to have it executed in another thread. Thereby I also hand over the array of arguments. I then wondered what the implications of simply `proceeding` with the intercepted method in the different thread would be.

Comment: SimonT, are you publishing the entire array, or just an element of it?

Answer (score 1):

The exact answer depends on the mutability of the array and its contents, the number of writers and readers, whether your only option is using an array (and not a thread-safe `Collection` of the same elements), etc.

If I was in your shoes, I'd probably spend an evening searching in StackOverflow and trying out some fancy combination of patterns (maybe `final` array reference plus immutable wrappers of the array elements, or a custom update scheme using `Unsafe.putOrderedObject` if there's a single writer).

Then after a short internal struggle, I'd copy all of it in my "Playground" folder and use an `AtomicReferenceArray` or a `CopyOnWriteArrayList` (or another appropriate off-the-shelf solution).

I'd also try to remind myself that I need to worry about performance when I've addressed all of my bigger concerns (like correctness), and when I have a proof that *this* specific part of my program needs to be optimized. Hopefully a similar approach will work for you too.